# lookml link's url | add value with quotes around value

Tags: looker, lookml

I am using Looker's link feature within my dashboard to filter a dashboard based on a selected `PRODUCT`. It usually works well but fails when PRODUCT has `#` within it. A workaround is to wrap the `value` within a double quote. How to I add double quote around the `value` argument within `url`?

```
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}."PRODUCT" ;;
    link: {
      label: "FILTER DASHBOARD ON THIS SKU"
      url:"https://xxx.cloud.looker.com/dashboards/1234?PRODUCT={{value}}"
    }
```